# Sequelize Many to Many Relationship Referring to the Wrong Column Name

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a RecipeIngredient table which contains the PK of Recipe and Ingredient tables as shown below:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('RecipeIngredients', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      recipe_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER, 
        references: { model: 'Recipes', field: 'id' }
      },
      ingredient_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER, 
        references: { model: 'Ingredients', field: 'id'}
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('RecipeIngredients');
  }
};
```

If I simply try to query the above table using the following code:

```
models.RecipeIngredient.findAll().then(all => console.log(all))
```

I get the following error:

```
Executing (default): SELECT "recipe_id", "ingredient_id", "createdAt", "updatedAt", "IngredientId", "RecipeId" FROM "RecipeIngredients" AS "RecipeIngredient";
Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: column "IngredientId" does not exist
```

Why does Sequelize thinks that there is a column named "IngredientId"? The name of the column is "ingredient_id".

UPDATED: Modal Definitions Added

Recipe:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  var Recipe = sequelize.define('Recipe', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {});
  Recipe.associate = function(models) {
    Recipe.belongsToMany(models.Ingredient, {
      as: 'ingredients', through: { model: models.RecipeIngredient, foreignKey: 'recipe_id'}
    })
    // associations can be defined here
  };
  return Recipe;
};
```

Ingredient:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  var Ingredient = sequelize.define('Ingredient', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {});
  Ingredient.associate = function(models) {
    Ingredient.belongsToMany(models.Recipe, { as: 'recipes', through: { model: models.RecipeIngredient, foreignKey: 'ingredient_id'}})
  };
  return Ingredient;
};
```

RecipeIngredient:

```
 'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  var RecipeIngredient = sequelize.define('RecipeIngredient', {
    recipe_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    ingredient_id: DataTypes.INTEGER
  }, {});
  RecipeIngredient.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
  };
  return RecipeIngredient;
};
```

Comment: show model definitions

Comment: @Anatoly I have updated the model definitions.

Comment: maybe you should indicate `otherKey` options in belongsToMany associations as well as you indicated `foreignKey` ones?

Answer (score 1):

In the file that you configure the database, put a define with it inside:

```
underscored: true,
underscoredAll: true,
freezeTableName: true,
```

Example of my config.js

```
require("dotenv").config();

module.exports = {
    dialect: process.env.DB_DIALECT,
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
    define: {
        timestamps: true,
        underscored: true,
        underscoredAll: true,
        freezeTableName: true,
    },
};
```

Comment: But why would it only complain about IngredientId.

Comment: @johndoe at your query(SELECT "recipe_id", "ingredient_id", "createdAt", "updatedAt", "IngredientId", "RecipeId" FROM "RecipeIngredients" AS "RecipeIngredient";
Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: column "IngredientId" does not exist ) IngredientId is called before RecipeId,  that's why it´s only complaining about the IngredientId

Comment: another thing to do, when you create the association, It is not necessary to create the field in the model definitions